# Spring Data MongoDB get document by inner object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In my Spring Boot / Spring Data MongoDB project I have a following POJO:

```
@Document(collection = "decision_analysis")
public class DecisionAnalysis {

    private String id;

    private DecisionAnalysisRequest decisionAnalysisRequest;

    private DecisionMatrixPageResponse decisionMatrixPage;

    private Date createDate;

    private HttpRequestData httpRequestData;

...

}
```

where `DecisionAnalysisRequest`:

```
public class DecisionAnalysisRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1493180175756424789L;

    private String decisionNameFilterPattern;

    private Set<BaseQuery> filterQueries;

    private Set<Long> sortCriteriaIds;

    private String sortWeightCriteriaDirection;

    private String sortTotalVotesCriteriaDirection;

    private Map<String, Double> sortCriteriaCoefficients;

    private Long sortCharacteristicId;

...

}
```

I need to lookup `DecisionAnalysis` documents by `DecisionAnalysisRequest` so I have created a Spring Data MongoDB repository with the following method:

```
@Repository
public interface DecisionAnalysisRepository extends MongoRepository<DecisionAnalysis, String> {

    DecisionAnalysis findByDecisionAnalysisRequest(DecisionAnalysisRequest decisionAnalysisRequest);

}
```

Right now this method only work when `filterQueries` is null. But when `filterQueries` is not null the method continuously returns no results.

`filterQueries` is an array of composite objects, for example:

```
 "filterQueries":[
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":711903,
         "characteristicName":"Body type",
         "value":[
            "Compact"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":712745,
         "characteristicName":"Sensor photo detectors (megapixels)",
         "value":[
            10,
            53
         ]
      }
   ]
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I adjust my code in order to properly look up `DecisionAnalysis` documents by `DecisionAnalysisRequest` even when the `filterQueries` contains data.

**UPDATE**

This is a sample `DecisionAnalysisRequest` document that I'm going to use as a key(information inside of this document varies each time per user selected on UI):

```
{
   "sortCriteriaIds":[
      711882,
      711887,
      711884,
      711899,
      711896,
      711897,
      711890,
      711891,
      711888,
      711889,
      711895,
      711892,
      711893
   ],
   "sortCriteriaCoefficients":{

   },
   "pageNumber":0,
   "pageSize":10,
   "sortWeightCriteriaDirection":"DESC",
   "sortid":null,
   "sortCharacteristicDirection":null,
   "sortDecisionPropertyName":null,
   "sortDecisionPropertyDirection":null,
   "decisionsIds":[

   ],
   "persistent":true,
   "includeChildids":null,
   "excludeChildids":null,
   "filterQueries":[
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":711913,
         "characteristicName":"Body material",
         "value":[
            "Aluminium alloy",
            "Brass",
            "Carbon fiber"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":711903,
         "characteristicName":"Body type",
         "value":[
            "Compact SLR",
            "Compact"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"EqualQuery",
         "characteristicId":712746,
         "characteristicName":"Sensor size",
         "value":"1/1.7\" (7.44 x 5.58 mm)"
      },
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":712895,
         "characteristicName":"Color space",
         "value":[
            "Adobe RGB",
            "ECI RGB",
            "Primary color space"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":712145,
         "characteristicName":"Other resolutions",
         "value":[
            "1008 x 672",
            "1024 x 1024",
            "1024 x 576"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":712738,
         "characteristicName":"Image ratio w:h",
         "value":[
            "1:1",
            "3:2",
            "4:3"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":712744,
         "characteristicName":"Effective pixels (megapixels)",
         "value":[
            9,
            44
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"EqualQuery",
         "characteristicId":712901,
         "characteristicName":"Color filter array",
         "value":"RGB color filter array"
      },
      {
         "type":"EqualQuery",
         "characteristicId":712921,
         "characteristicName":"Image stabilization",
         "value":"Sensor-shift"
      },
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":712944,
         "characteristicName":"Uncompressed format",
         "value":[
            "No",
            "RAW",
            "TIFF"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":712928,
         "characteristicName":"Image parameters",
         "value":[
            "Brightness",
            "Color",
            "Color Space",
            "Color Tone",
            "Contrast"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":712919,
         "characteristicName":"White balance presets",
         "value":[
            2,
            10
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":712917,
         "characteristicName":"Boosted ISO (minimum)",
         "value":[
            1762,
            10741
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":712950,
         "characteristicName":"File format",
         "value":[
            "3FR",
            "AGIF",
            "ARW"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":712918,
         "characteristicName":"Boosted ISO (maximum)",
         "value":[
            339298,
            2878034
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":713340,
         "characteristicName":"Normal focus range (cm)",
         "value":[
            22,
            131
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"EqualQuery",
         "characteristicId":713343,
         "characteristicName":"Lens mount",
         "value":"Leica M"
      },
      {
         "type":"AnyInQuery",
         "characteristicId":713325,
         "characteristicName":"Autofocus",
         "value":[
            "Center",
            "Continuous",
            "Contrast Detect (sensor)",
            "Face Detection",
            "Live View"
         ],
         "operator":"OR"
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":713341,
         "characteristicName":"Macro focus range (cm)",
         "value":[
            19,
            75
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":713342,
         "characteristicName":"Number of focus points",
         "value":[
            78,
            468
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":713388,
         "characteristicName":"Viewfinder resolution (dots)",
         "value":[
            633548,
            3722581
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"RangeQuery",
         "characteristicId":713386,
         "characteristicName":"Viewfinder coverage %",
         "value":[
            84,
            97
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: that is because it will try to compare the Object in mongo with the object you have passed as argument to the method using `equals` method. If none present in your class, it will take the default Equals method and will fail because it does a deep compare. Try defining a equals(and ofcourse hashcode) methog in your  DecisionAnalysisRequest class and not include `filterQueries` in your equals method definition.(needless to say, you should not include that in your hashcode as well)

Comment: Another solution could be to include a unique field like id in your `DecisionAnalysisRequest` class and query using that id. If your new Unique field is called `id`, Then your repositoryMethod will look something like this `findByDecisionAnalysisRequest_Id(...)`

Comment: @pvpkiran thanks for your answer. Why do I need to not include `filterQueries`  in my equals/hashcode methods ? `filterQueries`  is an important part of the the uniqueness of `DecisionAnalysisRequest` object. Also, I can't use any surrogate ID fields and according to my business logic the key is `DecisionAnalysisRequest` itself with all of the data inside(including `filterQueries`  as well)

Comment: of course you can use. Then in that case you should a deep  comparision of every sub field

Comment: I have already tried this and it doesn't work for some reason..

Comment: also, it is a good approach from the performance point of view ? will the performance for this lookup significantly degrade with a continuous data growth ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144196/discussion-between-alexanoid-and-pvpkiran).

Comment: Can you add a sample `DecisionAnalysis ` document that you are expecting `filterQueries` to return ?

Comment: @Veeram I have updated my question and added `DecisionAnalysisRequest` that I'm going to use as key for future `DecisionAnalysis` look up. Will it work effectively from performance point of view in case of continuous data growth ?

Answer (score 1):

The query is run on server side, so you have to look into performance from server stand point of view.

You'll hit the 16MB memory limit for document continuous data growth.

You've to use dot notation to reach to `filterQueries` embedded doc for comparison.

Below example if you like to match one of the filters.

```
@Query("{decisionAnalysisRequest.filterQueries :?0}")
DecisionAnalysis findByDecisionAnalysisRequest(BasicQuery filter);
```

The reason you dont get the response as your comparing the input `DecisionAnalysisRequest` against the database `DecisionAnalysisRequest`which has more `filterQueries`.

You should look into comparing criteria on the fields on the document/embedded document/embedded array oppose to compare the whole document/embedded document/embedded array.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to find `DecisionAnalysis` by `DecisionAnalysisRequest` object and not by the `BasicQuery`. `filterQueries` is only a part of DecisionAnalysisRequest

Comment: Np. Okay then you need to pass the whole document with same no of fields, order and values. How would you think it should work on mongodb side if you are only including part of `filterQueries` in the query ? Spring is essentially trying to convert your input to equivalent mongo query.I'm just trying to understand your use case.

Comment: I'm not including only filterQueries.. I have showed filterQueries only as example. I use the full DecisionAnalysisRequest(also with filterQueries) for DecisionAnalysis look up. Also, when I say that the data will growth - I mean I'll have a many millions of DecisionAnalysis documents stored at MongoDB but no one of these documents will hit the 16 mb limit.

Comment: Okay. Try debug to see what query is generated when you send  complete `DecisionAnalysisRequest`, just as shown in your update. This should work in equals comparison the way you have. You can create index on `DecisionAnalysisRequest` to begin with, but  I think it would be efficient if you can identify queryable fields as oppose to full document match.